# Why can't I move this element?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I want to reorder my fields in my Ubercart edit product form.

Everything works good for all fields except Product Information (the group with price, model, etc).. If I change the weight of this field it doesn't move.

If I change the weight of its children, it works. So I can reorder its children, all its brothers, but not the object itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the field group weights through the GUI at admin/content/node-type/your-node-type/fields ... just drag-drop the Product field group into your preferred place.